# Submit form to API with Guzzle

Tags: php, html, api, laravel, guzzle

I've just started using Guzzle in Laravel 5 and are currently trying to submit a form to an API, but I'm having trouble with setting the parameters in the API URL.

**Here is my code:**

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'URL for API/RegisterEmailAndCellPhoneNumber?cellphonenumber=cellphonenumber&emailaddress=emailaddress&programtag=programtag&programid=programid']);

<div class="form-group margin-bottom-sm">
    <label for="RegisterEmail">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="RegisterEmail" name="emailaddress">
</div>

<div class="form-group margin-bottom-sm">
    <label for="RegisterPhonenr">Phonenumber</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RegisterPhonenr" name="cellphonenumber">
</div>
```

Any suggestions how to do this?